# Find adjacent value in R

Tags: r

This is an example of my dataset

[image]

I am trying to return the value for Department. (Which in this case is Marketing).
The added trick is that I do not know which column "Department" is present in. (This example it is Col2).

The solution i am thinking involves the below

1. Identify which column has the string "Department". = colx
2. Identify which column has value, based on step 1. = coly
3. Return Value of [coly] where [colx] = "Department"

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

**Reproducible dataframe**

```
datt <-
  structure(
    list(
      Col1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a"),
      Col2 = c("b", "Department",
               "b", "b"),
      Col3 = c("c", "Marketing", "c", "c")
    ),
    class = c("spec_tbl_df",
              "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-4L),
    spec = structure(list(
      cols = list(
        Col1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                           "collector")),
        Col2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                           "collector")),
        Col3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                           "collector"))
      ),
      default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess",
                                            "collector")),
      skip = 1L
    ), class = "col_spec")
  )
```

Comment: How do you find the "value" column (Marketing)? Is it one column to the right of the Department column?

Comment: Thats correct. The value right adjacent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` to get row and column index where `'Department'` is present. Increment the column index by 1 and get corresponding value.

```
departemnt_row_col <- which(datt == 'Department', arr.ind = TRUE)
departemnt_row_col[, 2] <-  departemnt_row_col[, 2] + 1
data.frame(datt)[departemnt_row_col]
#[1] "Marketing"
```

Comment: Ronak, I was trying `datt %>% filter(across(everything(), ~ str_detect(.x, 'Department')))`, but it didn't return any rows. Does `across` work differently in `filter` ?

Comment: Yes, the code that you have tried is similar to `filter_all` meaning it will only select rows which has 'Department' available in all the columns. Check out the new `?if_any` function in `dplyr`.

Comment: Thank for Ronak, I owe you a coffee! I have a follow on question.  "departemnt_row_col[, 2] + 1" provides the value adjecent to the right. What if the value was adjacent one, then down one cell?

Comment: In that case you need to increase both row and col by 1. `departemnt_row_col <- departemnt_row_col + 1`

Answer (score 2):

Implementing the algorithm you described. Loop through the column names. Look for the column with "Department" in it and store the values as a vector for use later to subset rows. Then, look for the column that has "Marketing" in it, but only if the column with "Department" has already been found. Stop the loop once both have been identified, then use the results to subset.

```
colx <- NULL
coly <- NULL

for ( x in names(datt) ) {
    
    # Look for the column with "Department"
    if ( any(grepl("Department", datt[[x]])) ) {
        colx <- datt[[x]]
    }
    
    # Look for the column that has "Marketing"
    if ( !is.null(colx) & any(grepl("Marketing", datt[[x]])) ) {
        coly <- x
        break
    }
    
}

# Use the results to subset
datt[colx == "Department", coly]
```

Result

```
[1] "Marketing"
```